# Get Largest Inscribed Rectangle of a Concave Polygon

Tags: co.combinatorics, cg.comp-geom

I'm looking for an algorithm to find a set of largest inscribed rectangles of a concave polygon where each rectangle must be collinear with one of the edges of the polygon.

In other words, I want to continually cut my polygon down using rectangles until I am left with regions were the largest-inscribed rectangle is not sharing an edge with the original polygon.

Is there a known algorithm for this?

An example:

[image]

This post is related to another post: [Cover a Concave Polygon with a minimum number of rectangles](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12376/)

I am hoping to split up the questions so I can attract better answers.

Comment: Are you trying to find the largest _single_ rectangle (as described in the first paragraph), or are you trying to find an optimal _set_ of rectangles (as described in the second paragraph)?  The two problems are very different.

Comment: @JɛﬀE If I take a greedy approach of finding the largest *single* rectangle and use that rectangle to parition my polygon, I can iteratively perform this to get the set. Or, at least I think...

Comment: But which problem are you really interested in?  The greedy algorithm is unlikely to give you the optimal set (although it _might_ be a reasonable approximation).

Comment: @JɛﬀE, Maybe I don't understand what I am asking. I don't think I stated the solution need be optimal. Did I miss something?